# You need to ensure that WebApp1 uses the ASP.NET v4.7 runtime stack

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to ask a question that I have seen in an Azure exam and I do not understand.

> You plan deploy an Azure web app that will have the following
> settings:
>
> - Name: WebApp1
> - Publish: Docker container
> - Operating system: Windows
> - Region: West US
> - Windows Plan (West US): ASP-RG1-8bcf
>
> You need to ensure that WebApp1 uses the ASP.NET v4.7 runtime stack.
> Which setting should you modify?
>
> - Region
> - Operating system
> - Publish
> - Windows Plan
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question comes from a renewal quizz of a Microsoft Azure Certification...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to modify the `publish`  setting from  `DockerContainer` to `code`.

- While deploying the web app , if you choose the  `code` in `publish` setting then you will be able select the specific runtime language on which you want your webapp to run  as show below.

[image]

- While deploying the web app , if you choose the `DockerContainer` in `publish` setting then you won't  be able to select the runtime on which your web app has to run as shown in below:

[image]